# Eloquent select where date is equal or higher than today

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

Can you help me solving this problem?
I want to show all data from table 'auctions' where the date is equal or higher than today

here my current code :

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Auction::with('item','user')->get();
            // NOT WORKING $data = Auction::with('item','user')->where('date','>=',Carbon::now())->get();

            return Datatables::of($data)->addIndexColumn()->addColumn('option', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editItem">AJUKAN HARGA</a>';

                return $btn;
            })->rawColumns(['option'])->make(true);
        }

        return view('bid.index');
    }
```

Please anyone help me,, maybe you can rewrite the variable $data or any... thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the `date` column? Did you try logging the query?

Comment: the type of date column is date sir

Comment: Please don't call me sir. :) Can you share the result of `Auction::with('item','user')->where('date','>=',Carbon::now())->toSql()` please?

Comment: haha okee,, btw still error @RomeoSierra ,

Comment: What's the error? Can you post it?

Comment: already done sir, look at my new comment, thanks sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks for Romeo Sierra, because of you i can think about this one.

Its done guys by this one

```
        $data = Auction::with('item','user')->whereDate('date','>=',Carbon::now()->toDateString())->get();
```

dont forget to include

```
        use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Answer (score 1):

**use this**

```
$data=\App\Auction::where('date',CURDATE() >= $date)->get();
```